# guide to dependency ranges when developing a Haskell library

Tags: haskell, dependency-management

As a Haskell beginner, I'm working on a small library that I want to make public. One problem I have is that I don't know what I should do about the ranges of the dependencies I have. Does it make sense to set the range to the current MAJOR version, for example

```
network >= 2.6 && < 2.7
```

Should I consider testing with lower MAJOR versions?

Comment: I'll just leave it there http://pvp.haskell.org/

Comment: ok, I'll go with MAJOR versions and use the `==` syntax. I noticed that some libs have no version for some common libraries such as `lens` and `time`. Isn't this quite dangerous? Is it normal?

Comment: I suspect, they just head over the responsibility to stackage: https://www.stackage.org/lts

Comment: "Isn't this quite dangerous? Is it normal?" It might be an outright mistake, or they might be relying on stackage as @arrowd says (which might or might not be a mistake depending on who you ask -- it is kind of a perennial flamewar topos), or they might be relying on some other package through which they depend transitively on `lens` and `time` to pin the versions for them (which, though not ideal, isn't all that risky for very common and stable packages such as `lens` and `time` from which one only uses a subset of obvious core features  which would break half of Hackage if changed).

Answer (score 0):

The [Package Versioning Policy](http://pvp.haskell.org/) document specifies besr approaches to assigning versions for your own package.

If you don't want to get too deep into this, you can omit all version constrains on packages you are depending on and then ask [Stackage team](https://www.stackage.org/) to include your package in their releases (see **Authors** section). Once your package gets in, it would be Stackage's responsibility to make sure it builds fine.

Comment: "Once your package gets in, it would be Stackage's responsibility to make sure it builds fine". It is the other way around. The *maintainer* is responsible for ensuring the package works with the latest Stackage releases. All Stackage does in that respect is testing whether that it is indeed the case. Packages which don't work with the latest release are temporarily dropped from Stackage until they are fixed. Cf. the [Stackage Maintainers Agreement](https://github.com/fpco/stackage/blob/master/MAINTAINERS.md).

Comment: @duplode Yes, of course Stackage team wouldn't fix the code for the maintainer, but at least they will provide him exact requirements and error messages.